# Get the error of basis gates programmatically

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices, qiskit-runtime

I want to get the error rates of the basis gates of a backend. Is there a function that can achieve this functionality?

For example, I want the error rates of the basis gates rx, cx of ibmq_mumbai backend programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backend [`properties()`](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.providers.BackendV1#properties) method returns an instance of [`BackendProperties`](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.providers.models.BackendProperties) from which you can get the gate errors as follows:

At first, let's get a handle to the backend:

```
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider

provider = IBMProvider()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibm_brisbane')
```

Then, we get a reference to `BackendProperties`:

```
backend_props = backend.properties()
```

Now, we loop over the basis gates and display `gate_error` for each qubit:

```
for basis_gate in backend.configuration().basis_gates:
    print('>>', basis_gate)
    for gate_props in backend_props.gates:
        data = gate_props.to_dict()
        if data['gate'] == basis_gate:
            for param in data['parameters']:
                if param['name'] == 'gate_error':
                    print('  ', data['qubits'], param['value'])
```

---

Note that, `ibmq_mumbai` is no longer exist. However, an old snapshot of its data exists in [fake provider](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/providers_fake_provider) module. So, you can get error information by creating an instance of `FakeMumbai`

```
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeMumbai

backend = FakeMumbai()
```

then use it with the above code.